# How to force a confirmation step before certain perforce command?

Tags: command-line, perforce, administration

I am new to Perforce.

Is it possible in P4 to have a confirmation step before using some deletion command.

E.g.:

- deleting a workspace has no confirmation step
  ( P4 client -d workspace_name )
- deleting label has no confirmation step
  ( P4 label -d label_name)

Which I found dangerous.

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you find this dangerous? If there are open files in the workspace, p4 will not let you delete the workspace. Everything else is in the depot and can be recovered.

Comment: Hi, I have slightly change the question. I found it dangerous that some commands have no confirmation steps or required force flag (-f), because neither the administrator, nor the user are mistake-proof. A confirmation step let people think one last time before using an unrecoverable command. :-)

   Thomas

Comment: Isn't the -f flag the confirmation then? Since by default you do not need it, adding it in assumes that you are confirming the action.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the real danger - if Perforce will wipe out something that you can't get back, then that is generally why you have the -f flag. The one truly dangerous command - p4 obliterate - does require an explicit -y flag before it will do anything.

If you are concerned about modifications of the server meta data (client specs, labels, permissions tables, jobs etc), then I strongly recommend you set up a "Specs" depot. This creates a special depot in Perforce that version controls any changes users make to thing slike labels specs, branch specs, client specs etc. Can be really useful, and is the first thing I do on any new Perforce installation.

It's all in the docs. Try [this KB entry](http://kb.perforce.com/AdminTasks/UsingTheSpecDepot) for starters.